# Is it possible to make a specific section have a different syntax?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am working with `markdown` and writing snippets like:

````
    ```c
    int
    main()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    ```
````

It is highlighted as a `code` in `vim`.

[image: Vim]

However would it possible for the `c` section to have the syntax of a normal `c` file? I was checking out `pyvim` and it has such a feature.

[image: Pyvim]

Wondering if I can bring it in `vim`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upstream repo for the runtime files for markdown has a [README](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown#vim-markdown-runtime-files) which describes this. Add to your vimrc:

```
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['c']
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome stuff, @Hotschke. Thanks for demoing with my example and screen-shotting it.

Comment: Note, you can also use [pasticboy/vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown), which is more actively maintained. It might be more featureful.